# R: aggregate dataframe, conditionally counting factor variables

Tags: r, aggregate

I'm an R novice, and I can't seem to get this one: I want to aggregate factors in a dataframe by counting occurances of a particular value (in this case, of the value "Yes"). There are lots of N/As as well, as follows:

Current:

```
Agg  Factor1  Factor2  Factor3
A1   Yes      Yes      Yes
A1   Yes      Yes      No
A1   Yes      N/A      No
A1   N/A      No       N/A
A2   Yes      Yes      No
A2   N/A      Yes      N/A
A2   No       N/A      N/A
```

Desired result:

```
Agg F1 F2 F3
A1  3  2  1
A2  1  2  0
```

Ideally I'd like an answer is base R, as I'm trying to learn.. of course, if there's an easier solution that uses a package, I'd also be interested.

Data

```
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, na.strings = "N/A", text = 
"Agg  Factor1  Factor2  Factor3
A1   Yes      Yes      Yes
A1   Yes      Yes      No
A1   Yes      N/A      No
A1   N/A      No       N/A
A2   Yes      Yes      No
A2   No       Yes      N/A
A2   N/A      No       N/A")
```

Comment: Mmh, this (@G.Grothendieck's suggestion) doesn't seem to work, I think because there are N/As in the data. The sums are all N/A. Same with @rawr's suggestion.

Comment: Convert the columns to character and then use @rawr's solution: `dd[] <- lapply(dd, as.character)`.  Note that there are no NAs in `dd` because N/A is a factor level and not an NA.  If you intended it to be an N/A you will need to modify your `read.table` statement and use `sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. ", na.rm = TRUE" did it, and I corrected the read.table statement above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparisons against a factor work against the labels, so this will work regardless whether the Factor columns are factors or strings:

```
aggregate(dd[-1L]=='Yes',dd[1L],sum,na.rm=T);
##   Agg Factor1 Factor2 Factor3
## 1  A1       3       2       1
## 2  A2       1       2       0
```

Comment: Yes, my problem was the frequent NAs --- I couldn't see the wood for the trees. Adding `na.rm=TRUE` got me there. Thanks.